# win forms C++/CLI How to use .cpp class from header

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

Hello I have sample

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;

ref class RefClass 
{
public:
    int X;

    RefClass(int x)
    {
        X = x;
    }
};
```

How can I use this class in Form1.h? Like `RefClass^ d = gcnew WinFormsTest::RefClass();`

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         }
```

2nd Where i should place RefClass code in .h? or .cpp?

Comment: It looks like you try to work with C++/CLI without C++ knowledge. Wrong order. Start with native C++.

Comment: Place RefClass to h-file and include it to Form1.h. For every C++ class (native or ref) you can move its implementation to .cpp file using general C++ rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a RefClass.h file where you'll put the class declaration.
- Create a RefClass.cpp file where you'll put the class definition. The implementation.
- For using it in any other class you have to include
  RefClass.h first and then you can do `auto refClass = gcnew RefClass();`